# Возможно ли вернуть в качестве результата работы функции две переменные разного типа?

Tags: ассемблер, любой-язык

По заданию нужно создать форму расчета выражения, где все вычисления провести на `asm`, но у меня возник вопрос касательно любого языка программирования.

Есть такая ассемблерная вставка-функция. Она рассчитывает значение переменной `Y`в зависимости от значения выражения `B*C` по одной из двух формул:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и возвращает результат расчета выражения размером 2 байта.

```
short function(char X, char A, char B, char C, short Y) {


    _asm {
        mov al, BYTE PTR C
        mov bl, BYTE PTR B
        imul bl
        mov BX, 17
        cmp AX, 0
        Jg CHECK2

        CHECK2 :
        mov BX, 17
            cmp AX, BX
            jl MARK1
            Jge MARK2
            jmp EXIT

            MARK1 :
        mov AX, 0
            mov al, BYTE PTR A
            mov bl, BYTE PTR B
            imul bl
            mov CX, WORD PTR C
            add AX, CX
            mov BX, AX
            mov AX, 0
            mov al, BYTE PTR X
            imul al, al
            sub BX, AX
            mov WORD PTR Y, BX
            jmp EXIT

            MARK2 :
            mov AX, 0
            mov al, BYTE PTR C
            imul BYTE PTR C
            mov BX, AX
            mov al, BYTE PTR B
            imul BYTE PTR B
            sub BX, AX
            mov AX, 0
            mov al, BYTE PTR B
            mov ah, BYTE PTR A
            imul ah
            sub BX, AX
            mov WORD PTR Y, BX
            jmp EXIT

                EXIT : 
        
    }
    return Y;

}
```

Нужно заполнить поле "пример" на форме, куда записать одну из двух возможных формул расчета `Y`.

Вопрос: Можно ли как-то вернуть в качестве работы функции (на любом языке программирования) две переменные? И могут ли быть эти переменные разных типов?

Например, я хочу вернуть все тот же `Y` типа `short` и переменную `msg`типа `String`, в которую запишу выражение для расчета `Y`.
или я могу перевести результат расчета в `String` вне ассемблерной вставки. Можно ли тогда будет вернуть две переменные в качестве результата работы функции?

Например `return Ystr, msg;`

Comment: Можно вернуть структуру. Можно записать по переданным функции указателям...

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать через void пойнтер (void*) и передавать в параметры указатели и работать с ними, а уже в вызываемой функции делать приведение указателя.

Comment: @АндрейМаврин в данном случае не нужен `void*`, нужен указатель конкретного типа.

Answer (score 0):

2 переменные можно, например на С++:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> func(int a,int b){
    std::vector<int> r;
    r.push_back(a+b);
    r.push_back(a*b);
    return r;
};
```

И разного типа можно. Например, на Python:

```
def func(a,b):
    return a*b,str(a+b)
```

И на с++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::pair<int,string> func(int a,int b){
    std::pair<int,string> r;
    std::string c;
    cin >> c;
    r.first = a+b;
    r.second = c;
    return r;
};
```

Comment: Ни тот ни другой пример на C++ не демонстрирует возврат двух значений разного типа - возвращается вектор целых чисел. Целые числа внутри вектора, очевидно, одного типа.